# Sapply Stopping after the First Instance when Parsing XML

Tags: xml, r, sapply

<- updated for completeness (thanks to hrbrmstr for pointing it out)->

I'm trying to extract some data from Pubmed and I've been reading the example from [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=YLS9BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA54&ots=gJwOicNsOA&dq=sapply%20xmlvalue&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=sapply%20xmlvalue&f=false) (relevant diagram [here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=YLS9BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA54&ots=gJwOicNsOA&dq=sapply%20xmlvalue&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q=sapply%20xmlvalue&f=false)). 
A redacted version of my data looks like:

```
<PubmedArticleSet>
   <PubmedArticle>
      <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
         <PMID Version="1">11841882</PMID>
         <Article PubModel="Print">
            <PublicationTypeList>
               <PublicationType UI="D002363">Case Reports</PublicationType>
               <PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
            </PublicationTypeList>
         </Article>
         <MeshHeadingList>
            <MeshHeading>
               <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D016887">Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation</DescriptorName>
            </MeshHeading>
            <MeshHeading>
               <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D006323">Heart Arrest</DescriptorName>
               <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y" UI="Q000188">drug therapy</QualifierName>
               <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="Q000401">mortality</QualifierName>
               <QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="Q000628">therapy</QualifierName>
            </MeshHeading>
         </MeshHeadingList>
      </MedlineCitation>       
   </PubmedArticle>

   <PubmedArticle>
      <MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
         <PMID Version="1">11841881</PMID>
         <Article PubModel="Print">
            <PublicationTypeList>
               <PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
            </PublicationTypeList>
         </Article>
      <MeshHeadingList>
           <MeshHeading>
               <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D000368">Aged</DescriptorName>
           </MeshHeading>
           <MeshHeading>
              <DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N" UI="D016887">Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation</DescriptorName>
           </MeshHeading>
        </MeshHeadingList>
     </MedlineCitation>    
   </PubmedArticle>
</PubmedArticleSet>
```

So far, I've been able to nicely extract the PublicationTypes using the following code (please run the code in the top segment at the end of this post first):

```
utilAtype <- function(x){
        PMID <- xmlValue(x[[1]][[1]])
        PublicationType <- sapply(xmlChildren(x[["Article"]][["PublicationTypeList"]], omitNodeTypes = "XMLInternalTextNode"), xmlValue)
        data.frame(PMID = PMID, PublicationType=PublicationType, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

PMIDAType <- xpathApply(hdisease, '//MedlineCitation', utilAtype)
PMIDAType <-do.call(rbind, PMIDAType)
```

**PMID      PublicationType**

*11841882   Case Reports*

*11841882   Journal Article*

*11841881   Journal Article*

However, using a similar approach on the MeshHeadings results in sapply skipping the rest of the subnodes as below:

**PMID       LName**

*11841882   Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation*

*-Other entries for 11841182 Missing-*

*11841881   Aged*

Would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on this? The way it's done in the sample suggests that this approach should have worked with no issues.
Please see code below for reference.

```
require("XML")
xmlfile=xmlParse("file.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
hdisease = xmlRoot(xmlfile)
```

---

```
utilMesh <- function(x){
        PMID <- xmlValue(x[[1]][[1]])
        MHead <- ifelse(is.null(x[["MeshHeadingList"]]), NA, 
                sapply(xmlChildren(x[["MeshHeadingList"]], omitNodeTypes = "XMLInternalTextNode"), function(z) xmlValue(z[["DescriptorName"]])))
        data.frame(PMID = PMID, MHead=MHead, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }

PMIDMesh <- xpathApply(hdisease, '//MedlineCitation', utilMesh)
PMIDMesh<-do.call(rbind, PMIDMesh)
```

---

```
c<-nrow(PMIDMesh)
row.names(PMIDMesh) <- 1:c
nrow(table(PMIDMesh))

write.csv(PMIDMesh,"Mesh1.csv")
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. There are errors in the redacted XML sample and even when they are corrected your first code snippet does not produce the results you show.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Have edited my entry, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Before jumping in with an XML response, are you aware of the [pubmed.mineR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pubmed.mineR/)?

Comment: No I wasn't, thanks very much for pointing it out, I'll go look into it now.  I'd still be interested in why sapply is not performing as I expected it to though, if you happen to have the answer!

Comment: The package looks interesting but it seems to be quite centred around processing abstracts, so unfortunately it doesn't support extracting author and MeSH keyword information (my requirements are almost embarrassingly basic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use xpath instead, maybe...

```
library(rentrez)
x <- entrez_fetch("pubmed", "xml", id=c(11841882,11841881))
doc <- xmlParse(x)
pubs <- getNodeSet(doc, "//PubmedArticle")

y <- lapply(pubs, function(x) data.frame(
     pmid = xpathSApply(x, ".//MedlineCitation/PMID", xmlValue),
     mesh =  xpathSApply(x, ".//MeshHeading/DescriptorName", xmlValue)) )

do.call("rbind", y)

       pmid                          mesh
1  11841882 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation
2  11841882              Child, Preschool
3  11841882                        Female
4  11841882                  Heart Arrest
5  11841882                        Humans
6  11841882                        Infant
7  11841882                          Male
8  11841882         Retrospective Studies
9  11841882                  Time Factors
10 11841882        Vasoconstrictor Agents
11 11841882                  Vasopressins
12 11841881                          Aged
13 11841881 Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation
14 11841881         Electric Countershock
15 11841881               Family Practice
...
```